# Getting "Failure: Module initialization failed" error

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I have created a script file ( approximately 3-4 months before) capturing the live audio and it worked fine we are able to capture the live audio and also can hear from the headphone.

Here is my script file

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

function set_live_audio {
        #get the sink name
        sink=$(pactl list short sinks | grep "alsa_output" | awk '{ print $2 }' | head -n1)

        #get bluetooth sources
        pactl list short sources | grep "bluez_source" | awk '{ print $2 }' | while read bluetooth_source
        do
                if [ ! "$(pactl list short modules | grep source=${bluetooth_source} | head -n1)" ]; then
                        index=`pactl load-module module-loopback source=${bluetooth_source} sink=${sink} latency_msec=1 source_dont_move=yes`
                fi
        done

        #get alsa sources
        pactl list short sources | grep "alsa_input.usb" | awk '{ print $2 }' | while read alsa_source
        do
                echo $alsa_source
                if [ ! "$(pactl list short modules | grep source=${alsa_source} | head -n1)" ]; then
                        index=`pactl load-module module-loopback source=${alsa_source} sink=${sink} latency_msec=1 source_dont_move=yes`
                fi
        done
}

while true; do
        set_live_audio
done
```

Today I again ran this hand, but I didn't catch any live audio. I get 
"**Failure: Module initialization failed**" error.
I tried to resolve this error but no luck.

Here is my output of **pactl list short sources** command (with bluetooth on)

```
0   alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_D81A0330-00-U0x46d0x823_1.analog-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 32000Hz   RUNNING
6   alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_4B709030-00-U0x46d0x823.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 32000Hz   RUNNING
10  bluez_sink.00_1D_DF_44_DB_A6.monitor    module-bluetooth-device.c   s16le 1ch 8000Hz    RUNNING
11  bluez_source.00_1D_DF_44_DB_A6  module-bluetooth-device.c   s16le 1ch 8000Hz    RUNNING
```

So how can I resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Restart PulseAudio (killing the existing daemon if needed):

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Load the [PulseAudio module](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-alsa-sink) that provides an ALSA sink for Bluetooth devices:

```
sudo pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=bluetooth
```

Comment: Can you please explain how these commands work and what they do to fix the problem?

Comment: @KazWolfe I've edited the answer to explain what the commands do