# How to fix error "pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused" with bluetooth?

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

On Ubuntu 14.04 I have sometimes problems to connect to a bluetooth device (audio sink). Sometime it works, sometimes it does not work.

I have followed the solution [given here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689281/pulseaudio-can-not-load-bluetooth-module-15-10-16-04) and looked at [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519574/getting-failure-module-initialization-failed-error), but still I have the problem sometimes. I want to be able to use the bluetooth device as audio sink **without** rebooting my device!

I get the following errors:

```
> sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
Failure: Module initialization failed
```

I still have made the changes as suggested for the first solution.

Additional information:

- I have two bluetooth icons in my Status menu. Maybe there are competing apps/services/tools installed?
- When trying to connect to the audio sink using the `Bluetooth Manager` I get the message `Connection Failed: Stream setup failed`.

Comment: Which bluetooth applet do you use? `blueman-applet`? Or something else?

Comment: Check PulseAudio daemon is running: `pulseaudio --check --verbose`. Start it: `pulseaudio --start --daemonize`

Answer (score 2):

PulseAudio runs as your user, not as root, so there is not need to use `sudo`:

```
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```